# Android option not found in preferences

Tags: android

Normally i install eclipse and android-sdk by copying those folder to pc and change android preferences to my copied folder. In some laptop i dont found the android tab in preferences Why?...adt plugin installed

Thanks in advance

Comment: sounds like the ADT plugin is not installed in that Eclipse installation.

Comment: @goddchen No adt plugin is installed.

Comment: @Arju are u using indigo